# Some of _IE functions are failing in IE10?How to correct it

Tags: internet-explorer, autoit

`IELinkClickByText ($oIE, "Continue")` throws a warning:
`IE.au3 T3.0-1 Warning from function _IELinkClickByText, $_IEStatus_NoMatch`

`_IEAction ($oSubmit, "click")` throws an error:
`_IEAction(click), $_IEStatus_InvalidDataType`

Similarly many IE functions( `_IEPropertySet`, `_IEGetObjById`) are failing in IE10, even though these functions are working in IE9.

Can anyone suggest a solution to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling compatibility mode for IE before running your code.

```
    $64Bit = ""
    If @OSArch = "X64" Then
        $64Bit = "64"
    EndIf
If StringLeft(RegRead("HKLM" & $64Bit & "\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version Vector", "IE"), 1) > 8 Then ;Check for version 9 or later


  $wshNetwork = ObjCreate("WScript.Network")
  $struser = $wshNetwork.Username
  $objWMIService = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
  $objAccount = $objWMIService.Get('Win32_UserAccount.Name="' & $struser & '",Domain="' & @ComputerName & '"')
  RegWrite("HKU" & $64Bit & "\" & $objAccount.SID & "\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\", "AllSitesCompatibilityMode", "REG_DWORD", 1)
  RegWrite("HKU\" & $objAccount.SID & "\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\", "AllSitesCompatibilityMode", "REG_DWORD", 1)
EndIf
```

Comment: In --$objAccount.SID---what is SID stand for?